# What is the warranty on my Lumia 1020 and who should I contact?

Tags: nokia-lumia-1020

I bought my Lumia 1020 outright from my phone provider and have a receipt dated 24th April 2014. Shortly after receiving it I noticed a band of 'screen burn' across the top of the screen, which makes all my photos look like the Northern Lights are present! Another fault also appeared with my headphone jack so I took it to the shop of my phone provider (O2, in the UK) about 7 months from new. They sent it to be fixed and it was returned with the headphone issue resolved but not the screen burn. At the time it wasn't too bad and not annooying enough to bother with.

Now it is really getting quite bad and I'm not sure what to do. I'm just a few days short of two years since the receipt date and have no idea if I have 1 year or two year's warranty here in the UK.

Also, if this is Microsoft's issue or the company who sold me the phone (not on contract, I bought the phone up front)? I know companies like to try and push responsibility around so what is my situation and how should I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the store and just ask, without describing the actual problem?
Also be sure to point out that it has been repaired previously, since some stores extend the warranty (time) then or give a separate warranty on the repair itself (I don't live in the UK, so I can't be more specific than that).